# iOS - How to use existing dynamic library (.so file)

Tags: ios, xcode, shared-objects, dynamic-library

I have an existing dynamic library, and I try to use this library into my iOS app using `dlopen()`, but the function always return NULL. The library is a .so file and comes from an Android project. `dlerror()` return :

```
dlopen(/var/mobile/Applications/990CF1A9-B467-471B-9FDB-D0929D90B01D/Documents/libsamlib.so, 10): no suitable image found.  
Did find: /var/mobile/Applications/990CF1A9-B467-471B-9FDB-D0929D90B01D/Documents/libsamlib.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

My app won't be on the App Store, but I read on Internet that load an dynamic library is technically possible. Did someone already managed to load a .so dynamic library with dlopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the dynamic library that I wanted to imported has to be compiled with the iOS architecture. So, the solution I have found was to re-compiled all source files from the originally library, create a .dylib and `dlopen()` will work.
This [link](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1106378-2/systemes/apple/developpement-ios/dynamic-library-ios/) helped me a lot.